# How to position underline Text in React Native?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

How can I add border with some margin or padding ? I want to remove the extended underline broder on left side of details text The underline should be only below text Details how can I position it correctly ? I tried marginLeft and paddingLeft is not working. Code:

```
<TouchableOpacity>
    <View style={styles.underlineTextContainer}>
       <Text style={styles.imgText}>DETAILS</Text>
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>


underlineTextContainer: {
        borderBottomWidth: 2,
        borderColor: '#ffffff'
}

imgText: {
        fontFamily: Fonts.SourceSansProBold,
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        fontStyle: "normal",
        lineHeight: 16,
        letterSpacing: 0,
        color: "#ffffff", 
        paddingLeft: 25,
        paddingBottom: 5,
        textAlign: 'center'
    }
```

Applying above code gives me this:

[image]

But I want something like this:

[image]

Comment: try giving the style to Text component or give it a flex:1 style

Comment: @YashOjha I tried adding flex:1 to text component but then text becomes invisible. See updated question.

Comment: paddingLeft on text is causing the problem, just give the margin to the parent view

Comment: This is happening because your "DETAILS" tab view is extended to far left. can you share the outside views of TouchableOpacity so that I can explain how it can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of giving `paddingLeft: 25` on your text component's style give margin Left on the parent `View` component like this:

```
    underlineTextContainer: {
        borderBottomWidth: 2,
        borderColor: '#ffffff',
        marginLeft: 25,
}

imgText: {
        fontFamily: Fonts.SourceSansProBold,
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        fontStyle: "normal",
        lineHeight: 16,
        letterSpacing: 0,
        color: "#ffffff", 
        paddingBottom: 5,
        textAlign: 'center'
    }
```